# MS 2008 R2 Drops Remote Desktop Sessions in 10 seconds or less every time

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, connection

I'm adding a new 64-bit server to our domain.  Everything seems fine except when accessing the machine using remote desktop, after a few seconds the connection is lost.  The error message is "This computer can't connect to the remote computer."  "Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator."

A similar result with Telnet on port 3389.  I am able to connect but if I hit a key the connection to host lost.

The event log shows the successful login.  No errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: What client are you connecting from? There's known problems with XP and Vista.

Comment: Have tried disabling Anti-Virus? Are you connecting on the same LAN or  through a firewall/IDS/IPS?

Comment: I've had the same result from XP SP3, Vista (an older version of remote desktop and recently upgraded to the newest version available), and also from another server that is 64-bit and running windows 2008 Storage OS.  Everything is from inside a 1-domain lan.

The firewall is disabled on the server and the vista machine.

Another odd thing.  Sometimes I can login every time I try, other times I get the can't connect error.

I need to check anti-virus on the server but I don't remember seeing that.  Anti-virus is not running on the other machines.

Answer (score 1):

Bad NIC.  It provided network connectivity but no RDC.  NIC 2 works fine.